# construct graph nodes and edges from points and paths

Tags: geospatial, openstreetmap, graph-theory, graph-algorithm, spatial

I have an xml file (openstreetmap exported file) that has two types of elements called node (**it is not node of graph**) and way (a path in graph). Each point has a 64-bit identifier and coordinate and each path has a 64-bit identifier and a list of points references. for example:

```
<node id="1" lat="..." lon="..." />
<node id="2" lat="..." lon="..." />
<node id="3" lat="..." lon="..." />
<node id="4" lat="..." lon="..." />
<node id="5" lat="..." lon="..." />
<node id="6" lat="..." lon="..." />
<node id="7" lat="..." lon="..." />
<node id="8" lat="..." lon="..." />
<node id="9" lat="..." lon="..." />
<node id="10" lat="..." lon="..." />
<node id="11" lat="..." lon="..." />
<node id="12" lat="..." lon="..." />
<node id="13" lat="..." lon="..." />
<node id="14" lat="..." lon="..." />
<way>
    <nd ref="1" />
    <nd ref="2" />
    <nd ref="3" />
    <nd ref="4" />
    <nd ref="5" />
</way>
<way>
    <nd ref="6" />
    <nd ref="7" />
    <nd ref="2" />
    <nd ref="8" />
</way>
<way>
    <nd ref="9" />
    <nd ref="10" />
    <nd ref="4" />
    <nd ref="11" />
</way>
<way>
    <nd ref="6" />
    <nd ref="12" />
    <nd ref="9" />
    <nd ref="14" />
</way>
<way>
    <nd ref="5" />
    <nd ref="13" />
    <nd ref="14" />
</way>
```

How can I structure the graph using the above data?

For above example, the output should be as follows:

```
<node id="1" lat="..." lon="..." />
<node id="2" lat="..." lon="..." />
<node id="4" lat="..." lon="..." />
<node id="8" lat="..." lon="..." />
<node id="9" lat="..." lon="..." />
<node id="11" lat="..." lon="..." />
<node id="14" lat="..." lon="..." />
<edge>
     <n1 ref="1" />
     <n2 ref="2" />
</edge>
<edge>
     <n1 ref="2" />
     <n2 ref="4" />
</edge>
<edge>
     <n1 ref="2" />
     <n2 ref="9" />
</edge>
<edge>
     <n1 ref="2" />
     <n2 ref="8" />
</edge>
<edge>
     <n1 ref="4" />
     <n2 ref="11" />
</edge>
<edge>
     <n1 ref="4" />
     <n2 ref="9" />
</edge>
<edge>
     <n1 ref="4" />
     <n2 ref="9" />
</edge>
```

Is there a software or an algorithm that can solve this problem?

thanks.

Comment: Every routing engine for OSM like OSRM or GraphHopper solves this already: https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Routing

Answer (score 1):

If you're comfortable using Java, consider taking a look at [Atlas](https://github.com/osmlab/atlas). Atlas is an in memory representation of OSM data that will allow you to create a graph like the one you're describing above. It will also provide you with APIs for connectivity, routing and spatial searches.

Here's a common pattern from our test implementation, that shows how to create an Atlas from a .osm file. Code snippet:

```
public class TestAtlasTestRule extends CoreTestRule 
{
    @TestAtlas(loadFromJosmOsmResource = "yourOsmFile.osm")
    private Atlas yourAtlasFile;

    public Atlas getAtlasFile()
    {
        return this.yourAtlasFile;
    }
}
```